# How to unlist multiple list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a python lists and I want to list out all the objects in the list.

**lists**

```
product = ['https://www.jumia.com.ng/pancake-waffle-baking-mixes/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/porridge-oats/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/cold-cereals/']

          ['https://www.jumia.com.ng/laundry-bleach/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/liquid-detergent/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/powders-detergent/']
```

I want to list out all the object in the list in this **form**

```
'https://www.jumia.com.ng/pancake-waffle-baking-mixes/'
'https://www.jumia.com.ng/porridge-oats/'
'https://www.jumia.com.ng/cold-cereals/' 
'https://www.jumia.com.ng/laundry-bleach/'
```

I tried this `product_url = ','.join(product)` and I get a str of objects

```
'https://www.jumia.com.ng/pancake-waffle-baking-mixes/,https://www.jumia.com.ng/porridge-oats/'
```

Comment: ...what's your goal here?

Comment: Do you just want to print each item of your list?

Comment: @quamrana I want all the items to be printed out

Comment: Ok, see the answer below.

Comment: @quamrana I have a list of urls from a get request and  I want to list out all the individual url from the list.

The proposed method only list out items from the first list

Comment: Oh yes, I was going to ask about this. Your first snippet doesn’t make sense. There seem to be two lists, but only one variable, so you can only access the first list.

Comment: @quamrana Yes you are right, I noticed that as well. That was  how I got the response from the request
The for loop works fine and I have already find a way around the issue on my first code snippet..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over them:

```
product = ['https://www.jumia.com.ng/pancake-waffle-baking-mixes/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/porridge-oats/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/cold-cereals/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/laundry-bleach/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/liquid-detergent/', 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/powders-detergent/']

for link in product:
    print(link)
```

Since your question is very vague I don't exactly understand what you want to accomplish.